# The 'Adding and Removing Login Credentials' page has outdated screenshots

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center, screenshot

Looking through the new [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), I noticed [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/edit-logins) - the 'Adding and removing login credentials' page.

Here's the screenshots on that page, with current screenshots below them:

#### Old:

[image]

#### Current:

[image]

#### Old:

[image]

#### Current:

[image]

Could we at least use current screenshots?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the first screenshot, but I agree with the second one.

Comment: @DannyBeckett It's less noticeable, but the font sizes are slightly different, and info isn't displayed as if you were looking at your own profile. Also, he has 1,000,000 rep. Something people looking at this probably won't have :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated the "my logins" screenshot. The profile view is actually correct - you see a couple additional fields on your own profile, but for someone who has never flagged anything or changed their display name, they'd see what's in the screenshot.

And who knows, maybe someone will be inspired by the 1,000,000 rep and will set out to beat it. :)

Comment: Well... Jon Skeet would probably be there except for that dastardly repcap.

Comment: How did you get that screenshot, anyway? Private SO installation?